# Achieving Strong Consistency Using get_or_insert

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a model like this:

```
class UserModel(ndb.Model):
    ''' model class which stores all the user information '''
    fname = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    lname = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    sex = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, choices=['male', 'female'])
    age = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    dob = ndb.DateTimeProperty(required=True)
    email = ndb.StringProperty(default=None)
    mobile = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    city = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    state = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

Since none of above fields are unique, not even email becuase many people may no have email ids. So I am using the following logic to create a string id

```
1. Take first two letters of 'state' and change it to upper case.
2. Take first to letters of 'city' and change it to upper case.
3. Get the count of all records in the database and increment by one.
4. Append all of them together.
```

I am using get_or_insert for inserting the entity.

Though adding a user, will not happen too often but any kind of clash would be catastrophic, means probability of contention is less but its impact is very high.

My questions are:

```
1. Will using get_or_insert guarantee that I will never have duplicate IDs?
2. get_or_insert documentation says "Transactionally retrieves an existing 
   entity or creates a new one.". How can something perform an operation 
   "transactionally" without using a ancestor query.
```

PS: For several reasons I can't keep all the user entities in the same entity groups.

Comment: why don't you just force people to have email? I think most people online have email address.

Comment: This application is for managing operation for a company which operates in rural area. The users in User Model, will actually never login to portal. This application is only for the staff of the company.

Answer (score 3):

In order to provide transactionality, `get_or_insert` uses a [Datastore transaction](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions). In order to use a query in a transaction it must be an ancestor query, however transactions can also `get` and `put`, which don't require a parent to be set on the entity.

However, as @Greg mentioned, you absolutely do not want to use this scheme for generating user ids. In particular, doing a count on your db is incredibly slow and will not scale, and is eventually consistent. Because the query is eventually consistent, it may return a count smaller than the actual count as long as results are eventually consistent (which for a large app will be all the time). This means you could wait several hours before an insert would actually succeed.

If you want to provide a customer ID with a State and City, I would recommend doing the following:

1. Do a put using automatic ids.
2. Expose to the user a "Customer ID" which is the State + City + ID.
3. When you want to lookup a customer given their "Customer ID", just do a get for the ID portion.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! This really clarifies the doubt and also saves me from counting entities in the User Model. I will use the algo which you suggested.

Comment: In case you can help, how in general some one can have incremental IDs in datastore. All the ways I can think of, comes at a cost of either performance or consistency.

Comment: It is possible to have incremental counters using a sharded counter: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters. However, it is generally a bad idea to store values in a monotonically increasing fashion in the datastore: http://ikaisays.com/2011/01/25/app-engine-datastore-tip-monotonically-increasing-values-are-bad/

Answer (score 0):

if you keep that ID scheme (for which you honestly don't really need steps 1 and 2, just 3), there is no reason for it to create duplicate IDs.  With get_or_insert, it'll look for the exact ID you provide and fetch it if it exists, or simply create it if it doesn't, as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get_or_insert).  So you CANNOT have duplicate IDs  (well if you have this ID as your forced key in your model).  if you follow the link provided it clearly states that :

> > The get and subsequent (possible) put operations are wrapped in a transaction to ensure atomicity. Ths means that get_or_insert() will never overwrite an existing entity, and will insert a new entity if and only if no entity with the given kind and name exists.

And the fact it does it transactionnaly means it'll lock up the entity group to be sure you don't have contention.  Since you don't seem to have ancestors I think it'll just lock the entity you're updating

Comment: "it'll look for the exact ID you provide and overwrite it if it exists" will it overwrite or fetch if it exists ??

Comment: @VivekJha Sorry I mispoke (or miswrote).  It won't overwrite it, it'll return it (fetch).  I'm editing right now :)

Comment: Step 1 and 2 are required because this ID will be customer ID as well, hence by looking at customer ID we can make out to which city and state he belongs. This is mainly because of business perspective.

Comment: So yeah you can keep it.  Since your number is an auto-increment and will never hit duplicates, my point still stands.  I figured you probably had a business need to state + city even if from a technical point of view it means nothing.

Comment: As per my understanding, locking can happen only in case of ancestor queries. But here in this case I have no ancestors !! So does any window of probability exists in which I might have a duplicate ID?

Comment: well locking is for an entity group.  If you don't have any ancestors, it'll still lock your entity "group"... which, in the absence of parents/childs is just your entity.  There is no reason for duplicate IDs, you're forcing the IDs with your steps 1-4, so no matter what happens you'll never push the same ID to your database.

Comment: While "you can't have duplicate IDs" is (obviously) true, this won't prevent two records attempting to save to the same ID, which would be just as 'catastrophic'. Querying for the count is racy (and slow!), and can't be transactional unless your UserModels share an ancestor.

Comment: @Greg true, but he would need to have a customer from the same state and city to do that.  And while querying for the count is bleh, I didn't think it part of his question.  there is of course a way to use sharded counters to keep track of that number.  If he does use counters, I would update the shards BEFORE pushing the data, so even if two users from the same city/state are added, the counter will already be pushed so the ID will still be different